# Unable to save data into a MYSQL database using JAVA

Tags: java

I've been trying to save data on mySQL database called ingreso_datos however when I hit save button is not writing anything. Any suggestion? Thanks!

```
private void jButton_guardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    try {
        Connection con = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ingreso_datos (nombre_pelicula, anno_creacion, director, link_imdb, generos, nombre_soundrack_principal, interpretes, autor, total_pistas, Ganador_Oscar, Banda_Sonora, interpretes_banda_sonora, autor_banda_sonora, ganador_mejor_banda_sonora) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?");

        ps.setString(1, jTextField_nombrePelicula.getText());
        ps.setString(2, jYearChooser_annoCreacion.toString());
        ps.setString(3, jTextField_director.getText());
        ps.setString(4, jTextField_linkIMBD.getText());
        ps.setString(5, jComboBox_generos.getSelectedItem().toString());
        ps.setString(6, jTextField_nombreSoundtrackPpal.getText());
        ps.setString(7, jTextField_interpretesSoundtrack.getText());
        ps.setString(8, jTextField_autor_soundtrack.getText());
        ps.setString(9, jTextField_totalPistas.getText());
        ps.setString(10, jComboBoxGanadorOscarMejorCancion.getSelectedItem().toString());
        ps.setString(11, jTextField_bandaSonora.getText());
        ps.setString(12, jTextField_interpreteBandaSonora.getText());
        ps.setString(13, jTextField_autorBandaSonora.getText());
        ps.setString(14, jComboBoxGanadorMejorBandaSonora.getSelectedItem().toString());

        ps.executeUpdate();
        if(ps.executeUpdate() != 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Información ingresada satisfactoriamente");

            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " ¡Error! Información no fue ingresada.");

            }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

}                                               
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ9BQ.png)

Comment: can you please add the error log?

Comment: Thanks for your promptness. There's no error log... That's the interesting part...

Comment: please print the stacktrace.  `catch (SQLException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}      `

Comment: Thanks for letting me know!!!

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

correct the sql syntax. Bracket is not closed in the end. Close it

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ingreso_datos (nombre_pelicula, anno_creacion, director, link_imdb, generos, nombre_soundrack_principal, interpretes, autor, total_pistas, Ganador_Oscar, Banda_Sonora, interpretes_banda_sonora, autor_banda_sonora, ganador_mejor_banda_sonora) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```